# Repository.Commit() is throwing EmptyCommitException even though there are changes in the working directory

Tags: c#, libgit2sharp

I have code that's the equivalent of this

```
public static async Task CopyAndRestAndCommitFile(Stream content,
                                                  string branchName,
                                                  string sha)
{
    CreateOrResetBranch(branchName, sha);

    await Copy(content);

    Commit("changed");
}

private static async Task Copy(Stream content)
{
    var filePath = @"C:\temp\libgit2sharpTestRepo\fileToChange.txt";
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath,
                                           FileMode.Create, 
                                           FileAccess.Write,
                                           FileShare.None,
                                           32 * 1024,
                                           useAsync: true))
    {
        await content.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
    }
}

private static void CreateOrResetBranch(string branchName, string startPoint)
{
    //This Replaces git -B \{branchName} \{startPoint}
    using (var repo = new LibGit2Sharp.Repository(RepositoryPath))
    {
        var branch = repo.Branches[branchName];
        if (branch == null)
        {
            branch = repo.CreateBranch(branchName, startPoint);
            repo.Checkout(branch);
        }
        else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(startPoint))
        {
            repo.Checkout(branch);
        }
        else
        {
            var commit = repo.Commits.Single(c => c.Sha == startPoint);
            if (commit != null)
            {
                repo.Checkout(branch);
                repo.Reset(ResetMode.Hard, commit);
            }
        }
    }
}

private static void Commit(string message)
{
    // this replaces git add -A
    //               git -m \{message}
    using (var repo = new Repository(RepositoryPath))
    {
        repo.Stage("*");
        repo.Commit(message);
    }
}
```

With the `CopyAndRestAndCommitFile()` as an entry point. For some reason `repo.Commit(message)` always throws `LibGit2Sharp.EmptyCommitException` even though the file on the disk has changed. If I go and run `git status` from the command line before calling the commit function, the commit succeeds.

It's not a timing issue, because it doesn't matter how long of a delay I put between the `Copy()` and `Commit()` functions, the issue happens. It also doesn't matter how many times I repeat the `Commit()` function, it always throws the exception until I run `git status` from the command line on the repo.

The odd thing is that the code above doesn't quite reproduce the issue, but the only difference between that and the actual code is that the actual code is running in ASP.NET context and the stream we are copying is a Request Content stream.

What can I do to debug this issue?

Comment: `EmptyCommitException` is raised when the tree about to be committed matches the tree from the parent commit. This means that no modification has been detected. My guess is that is related to a known issue in libgit2 (see https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/pull/688).

In order to confirm that, can you (temporarily) tweak your code so that we're sure that the files are of **different** sizes?

Comment: Also, in order to make sure that the change has been promoted to the staging area, can you please output `repo.Index["fileToChange.txt"].Id` before and after the call to `Stage()`?.

Comment: ah Thanks @nulltoken, that's exactly what's going on. All the contents that the test case is checking [are of the same size](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/blob/master/Kudu.FunctionalTests/Vfs/VfsControllerBaseTest.cs#L23-L27). It didn't occur to me that it might be related to the file size. I'm not sure what the second comment is referring to!

Comment: Creating a proper answer as it seems we've narrowed down a first approach at resolving the problem.

Comment: *"I'm not sure what the second comment is referring to!"* -> That was a way to check if the change has been detected. A different oid would indicate that the change has been properly staged. The same oid would point at the change on disk not being detected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EmptyCommitException` is raised when the tree about to be committed matches the tree from the parent commit. This means that no modification has been staged.

As your scenario demonstrates some staging being done, my guess is that is you're encountering a known issue in libgit2.

`repo.Stage()` is an operation which promotes the changes that happened in the workdir directory to the `Index`. In order to do this, LibGit2Sharp runs a diff between the working directory and the index.

However, in order to avoid excessive oid calculation, a current libgit2 heuristic "skips" a file if its size on the disk is the same than what the index knows AND if the modified time hasn't been changed. The problem is that, according the the orginal git design, timestamps are stored in the index with a precision of one second.

Thus, when, within the same second, you stage twice a file without changing its size, the second one is going to be undetected by the libgit2 diff algorithm.

See http://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/pull/688 for more details.

Comment: Regarding to the explanation above, could you please elaborate on *"It's not a timing issue, because it doesn't matter how long of a delay I put between the Copy() and Commit() functions, the issue happens."*?. If you wait for 2 seconds, is the `EmptyCommitException` thrown?

Comment: The sleep I had was before `Commit()` not before `Copy()`. So you end up with a file change, then commit `T` time after, then file change in the same second then trying to commit `T` time after. either changing the content size or adding the sleep before writing resolves the issue